# Retrieving connection pool from Knex (to share it with express-mysql-session)

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, express-session

I've got *knex* configured to use MySQL with pooling:

```
var knex = require("knex")({
    client: "mysql",
    connection: {
        host: ...,
        user: ...,
        password: ...,
        database: ...
    },
    pool: {
        min: 0,
        max: 20
    }
});
```

I'm also using *express-session* and I'm planning on a switch to *express-mysql-session* for the store.

So, I want to use the connection pool that *knex* creates, so I can use the same pool for all DB access.

Is there any way to get a connection pool from *knex* that I can pass to the MySQL session store constructor? Or some other way to use the same pool for everything?

Comment: Have you guys find a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, I filed a feature request at https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1824.

A suggestion given there for my particular use case was to perhaps create an *express-knex-session* module, which I am going to do as soon as I can. I will update this with a link when I do.

Comment: Have you coded it?

Comment: @Contestosis Oh wow; this project seems so long ago. Tbh I don't remember; if I did I can tell you I didn't release it; unless it's on the github page for that project (although I can't remember what it was called or if it was public or not, or if it actually *has* a github page, lol). If I have a chance I'll totally look around to see if I've got that code somewhere and let you know. I'm sorry, I wish I had a more promising answer!

Comment: (That project got canned before it was finished, though -- client was a start-up company that imploded, as they do... so there's a pretty decent chance I never actually implemented this.)